# Angular material Toolbar with List style not working

Tags: angular-material

If I put `mat-nav-list` inside `mat-toolbar`, the nav list's height is not wrapped inside the toolbar, I didn't use any overridden CSS. What I want is that the nav list can fix inside mat-toolbar, because I'd like nav list to display as flex col or flex row on different size screen.
What can I do to fix it?

[stackblitz link to show the problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ynz1vk?file=package.json)